# Can I browse a locally hosted web site from a USB connected device?

Tags: chrome-for-android, usb-debugging, reverse-tether

I am attempting to [remote debug](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging) a locally hosted web application on Nexus 7 and 10 tablets running Android 4.2.2, that are connected to a development machine via USB. My goal is to browse to the equivalent of 127.0.0.1:xxxx on the tethered PC (so from the tablet I would expect to browse via the host PC's IP address 192.168.1.100:xxxx).

I do realize this can be accomplished utilizing Wi-Fi, but unfortunately the tablets are not connected to the same network as my development PC and can not be. Bluetooth is also out as my dev machine does not have Bluetooth.

It seems like utilizing reverse tethering would allow me to browse to the host machine. The reverse tethering solutions I've tried to utilize have focused on simply using the PC as a pass through to the internet. In any event I have not been able to successfully setup reverse tethering much less browse to the web application hosted on the connected development machine.

Using a USB reverse tether solution is it possible to browse a locally hosted web application? Is there an alternative to reverse tethering that will provide the same capability? Can I browse a locally hosted web site from an Android device connected via USB?

Comment: As 127.0.0.1 (alias "localhost") is the device you are on, this is unlikely to work. But instead, you could use the IP set for inside your local network (usually 192.168.*.*). Have you tried that? IMHO this should do even via USB tethering, as the tethered device is part of the same network.

Comment: @Izzy I definitely understand that localhost is only available from the host machine. In fact one of my favorite geek jokes is: "there's no place like 127.0.0.1". Irregardless I refactored the question as I don't think the previous iteration was as clear as the current version. It boils down to running a web app on a dev box and browsing to that web app from an Android device connected via USB.

Comment: Yes, that was my understanding (besides: nice joke, I like that ;) So have you tried it with the "local network address", as I suggested? Did it work? Or is that not possible as the web-app only listens to `localhost`? In the latter case, some VPN solution might do the trick (not sure, never did VPN myself).

Comment: Can your PC connect to the tablet? If so, ssh reverse port forwarding might allow for tablet-to-PC connection.